# RPI Pico GPIO output not producing square wave

Tags: electrical-engineering

I have an RPI Pico that is configured to pulse GPIO 5 every 1000 microseconds to control a stepper driver. For some reason, this pins output does not produce a square wave, instead I am seeing a gradual decrease in voltage when it is pulled low. This results in the stepper driver not functioning.

The odd thing is, when I measure the voltage using the oscilloscope, the driver works. I was thinking this may be functioning as a pull down resistor, however, enabling pull down on the pin does not make it work...

I have also tested other stepper driving pins and they produce a nice square wave and work.

Here is the schematic for the board:
[image: Board schematic]

Here is the waveform observed on GPIO 5:
[image: GPIO 5 waveform]

What could be causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Update: I ended up soldering a 10k resistor between stp and ground. The driver now works, but I still do not understand why a pull down was required on this pin but not any others...

Comment: Everything has capacitance, and different paths may be used going from low to high vs high to low.